# Python 2.7: cannot import name RoboBrowser ¿Como soluciono esto?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy intentando correr un Script de Python, pero al importar RoboBrowser me muestra " cannot import name RoboBrowser " como si no estuviera instalada.

La instale mediante **pip** y al ejecutar el comando pip freeze me aparece dicho framework, intente con python -c "import robobrowser" y me arroja el error nuevamente. He des-instalado el roboBrowser y lo he instalado de nuevo y no funciona tanto con **pip** install robobrowser y **easy install** robobrowser.

Si en algo ayuda al problema mi sistema operativo es Windows 7.

Mi versión de python es 2.7, la versión de *roboBrowser* 0.5.3

Este es mi código :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open('http://******')

signup_form = browser.get_form(id_='form1')
signup_form['user[ctl14$txtUserName]'].value = '***@gmail.com'
signup_form['user[ctl14$txtPassword]'].value = '1111'

print(signup_form.serialize())

browser.submit_form(signup_form)
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con este problema?

Comment: ¿No tendrás un script (o este mismo que ejecutas) llamado robobrowser.py en tu directorio actual por casualidad?

Comment: Gracias! @FJSevilla